# Assigning an object to a property from a QList

Tags: c++, qt

In my main app class I have a property which contains a list of the ProjectItems. Within my application a user can specifically select a an item in that list which I then assign to the property called currentProjectItem.

I know in same applications you would use a pointer here to point to the selected item in the list, in my case I'm just assigning that item to the 'currentProjectItem' property directly as seen below. The reason being, is the selected one can possibly be changed by the user and i don't want the original one in the list to be affected. Are there any issues in the way my code is written? Only ask because im a bit new to C++ and Qt. The app seems to be working as expected, I'm just not sure if what im doing is unstable.

I wasn't sure if i needed to set `currentProjectItem = nullprt` before assigning it a new value or something like that.

**.h file**

```
class AppCore : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

  Q_PROPERTY(QList<ProjectItem> projectItems READ getProjectItems
                 NOTIFY projectItemsChanged)
  Q_PROPERTY(
      ProjectItem currentProjectItem READ currentProjectItem WRITE
          setCurrentProjectItem  NOTIFY currentProjectItemChanged)

public:
  ~AppCore();

  static AppCore *instance();

  ProjectItem currentProjectItem ();

  void setCurrentProjectItem(const ProjectItem &item);

private:
  static AppCore *m_instance;

  explicit AppCore(QObject *parent = nullptr);

  QList<ProjectItem> getProjectItems() const;
  ProjectItem m_currentProjectItem ;

signals:
  void projectItemsChanged();
  void currentProjectItemChanged();
};
```

**.cpp file**

```
void AppCore::setCurrentProjectItem (const &ProjectItem&item) {
  m_currentProjectItem = item;
  emit currentProjectItemChanged();
}
```